# how to solve this error list index out of range?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, dictionary

i want to calculate the fpr and tpr for each confusion matrix but i receive this error

```
def true_false_positive(matrix):
tpr=[]
fpr=[]

for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    tpr[i]= matrix[i,0,0]/(matrix[i,0,0]+matrix[i,0,1])
    fpr[i]= matrix[i,1,1]/(matrix[i,1,0]+matrix[i,1,1])

return tpr, fpr
```

when i initialed tpr and fpr as dic it worked but i want them as arrays cuz i will do more calculates later
when i execute
true_false_positive(matrix1)
i receive

```
      5     for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
----> 6         tpr[i].append(matrix[i,0,0]/(matrix[i,0,0]+matrix[i,0,1]))
  7         fpr[i]= matrix[i,1,1]/(matrix[i,1,0]+matrix[i,1,1])
  8 

 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You can't do `tpr[...]` if your `tpr` is an *empty* list. Empty list doesn't even contain 0th element.

Comment: you are trying to access an element that is not there with `tpr[i]` and `fpr[i]` instead  just do `tpr.append()` and `fpr.append()`

Comment: yeah true i didn't pay attention, thank you so much it's solved

Answer (score 1):

thank you i changed it and it woked

```
def true_false_positive(matrix):
tpr=[]
fpr=[]

for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    tpr.append(matrix[i,0,0]/(matrix[i,0,0]+matrix[i,0,1]))
    fpr.append(matrix[i,1,1]/(matrix[i,1,0]+matrix[i,1,1]))

return tpr, fpr
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).